# What could be the possible HTML structure for this, using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to know that what could be possible HTML structure of the image(in link) below, if i use bootstrap.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/y7jcvuvehr9a4br/html.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Do you have any HTML that you've tried so far?

Comment: here i found the solution... and adjusted according to my needs.
http://codepen.io/escapedcat/pen/eokar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I found the solution and adjusted according to my needs.

```
[codepen](http://codepen.io/escapedcat/pen/eoka)
```